# Hide and show a view using angular2

Tags: angular

I want to display a page in my template only if it satisfy a condition when the user log in. 
 I have used ngIf* but I dont know where I have to put it, whether in the routing page or the component's page.

I have tried a code: the page still displayed in the menu of the template only its content is hidden. also I get an error

> Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'Layouts'
>   here is the code

```
 import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
 import { user }       from './forms/user';
 @Component({
 selector: 'forms',
 template: `<router-outlet *ngIf="!show"></router-outlet>`,

 })
 export class Forms {
 show: boolean=false;
 }
```

Can any one help me please!

Comment: The syntax is `*ngIf="..."`. Not `ngIf*="..."`. Closing for typo.

Comment: Thanks! this error disappear ! but it didn't solve my problem and  another error appear `Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'Layouts'`

Comment: Why would you want to hide outlets anyway, they are not component nor are they container for components, also, that's the reason you got that last error you posted, the unamed (primary) outlet was removed by `*ngIf`

Comment: @Dummy I didn't know where I have to put `*ngIf` to hide a page from my template. Have you any idea where I have to put it!

Comment: Put it on the component you want to remove. Also, note that `ngIf` **renoves** the element from the DOM. To toggle the `style.display` use style binding

Comment: do you need to hide some data or hide the entire component

Comment: @ArunKumaresh I want to hide the entire component

Comment: use guards to restrict the user to entire into the particular component

Comment: If I use guards, the component that I have hidden it, the name of the page still displayed in the menu of the template ?

Comment: are u using angular latest relase i:e 4 if yes then u can use the if else syntax that is provided put the who component template inside a if i dnt think you can use structural directives with router outlet

Comment: you're saying about which menu there is no menu in the question which you have posted

Comment: my menu.ts
      `export const PAGES_MENU = [
     { path: 'pages', children: [ {path: 'dashboard', data: { menu: {title: 'dashboard' } }   }, {  path: 'components', data: { menu: {title: 'mypage'  }
        },  children: [ { path: 'page1',data: { menu: { title: 'page1',  } } }  ]   }  }]
} ];  `

I have added my template 's menu! what I want to do is : when the user log in, if the user is an admin  the page1 is displayed for him anf if he is a normal user the page1 doesn't appear for him in the application

Comment: <div *ngIf="admin">Admin menu</div> <div *ngIf="normaluser">Normal menu</div> Update your question with template menu so it will easy to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

> Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'Layouts' here is the code

Because you are removing router outlet from dom because of condition and angular is not able to find the primary router outlet and throw error. You should not use ngIf on router outlet. You can use ngIf inside html for manuplate html for what to show or hide based on condition.

```
<div *ngIf="!show">
 Some data
</div>

Opposite 

<div *ngIf="show">
 Some data
</div>
```